Warning .tmp_vmlinux1 had a load segment with rwx permissions
home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-Linux-gnu-ld: warning: tmp vmlinuxl has a LOAD segment with RWX PERMISSIONS
WX permissions /home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: fs/read_write.o: in function 'vfs_read': /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme C25 C25s Narzo-50A-Androids-kernel-source/out/../fs/read_write.c:452:(.text+0
x7ac): undefined reference to ksu vfs read hook!
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-Linux-gnu-ld: fs/read write.o: relocation R AARCH64 ADR PREL P
G HI21 against symbol ksu vfs_read_hook' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with fPIC /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme C25 C25s Narzo-50A-AndroidS-kernel-source/out/../fs/read write.c:452:(.text+0
x7ac): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme_C25_C25s_Narz 0-50A-AndroidS-kernel-source/out/../fs/read write.c:452:(.text+6x7be): undefined reference to ksu_vfs_read_hook
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: fs/exec.o: in function do execveat common /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme C25 C25s Narzo-50A-AndroidS-kernel-source/out/../fs/exec.c:1728:(.text+0xlee4
): undefined reference to ksu execveat hook
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: fs/exec.o: relocation R AARCH64 ADR PREL PG HI21 against symbol ksu execveat hook which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recom
pile with -TPIC
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme_C25 C25s Narzo-50A-AndroidS-kernel-source/out/../fs/exec.c:1728:(.text+0xlee4
): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme C25 C25s Narz 0-50A-AndroidS-kernel-source/out/../fs/exec.c:1728:(.text+0xlee8): undefined reference to 'ksu execveat hook
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: drivers/input/input.o: in function input handle
event: /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme C25 C25s Narzo-50A-Androids-kernel-source/out/../drivers/input/input.c:380:(, text+0x328): undefined reference to ksu input hook
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-Linux-gnu-ld: drivers/input/input.o: relocation R AARCH64 ADR PREL PG HI21 against symbol ksu input hook which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared obje
ct; recompile with fPIC
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme_C25_C25s_Narzo-50A-Android5-kernel-source/out/../drivers/input/input.c:380:(. text+0x328): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation.
/home/zylex/Desktop/project/zyc-clang/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: /home/zylex/Desktop/project/realme_C25_C25s_Narz 0-50A-Androids-kernel-source/out/../drivers/input/input.c:380:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to 'ksu input_h
enter image description here
It occurred when I was building 4.19 android kernel
I tried searching on the web for a solution but didn't found any solution.
